# Función que devuelve un boolean dependiendo de si existe un usuario logeado en Firebase con "onAuthStateChanged"

Tags: angular, firebase

Necesito que una función me devuelva un boolean despendiendo de si un usuario está iniciado o no lo está.

```js
comprobarAutentificacion()
  {
    let valorControl = false;

    this.angularFireAuth.onAuthStateChanged(user=>{
      
      if(user)
      {
        valorControl = true;   
      }
     
     
    });
     return valorControl;
  }
```

Necesito que el **valorControl** cambie de falso a verdadero dependiendo de si el usuario existe cuando se comprueba en el **onAuthStateChanged**, pero intuyo que al ser asincrono el javascript me devuelve  el return con el valor original "**false**" antes de que **onAuthStateChanged** compruebe el si existe el usuario, intuyo que tengo que usar una promesa pero no sé cómo hacerlo.

**EDICIÓN 1**

Añado información:

La función que he escrito arriba está en un servicio. A ese servicio accedo desde una función en un componente:

```js
comprobarAutentificacion()
  {
    
    console.log("Valor de la variable " + this.miservicio.comprobarAutentificacion());
  }
```

Pero veo que esa llamada a la función del servicio desde el componente no me devuelve nada.

Comment: Esta pregunta responde lo que necesitas? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62099759/how-to-wait-for-firebase-auth-before-starting-angular-app

Comment: Podrías agregar un poco mas de contexto en qué componente o servicio estás tratando de usar esta función?

Comment: Acabo de editar la pregunta con la EDICIÓN 1

Answer (score 1):

El método `onAuthStateChanged` es para cuando necesitas observar los cambios en el usuario. En tu caso lo que quieres es simplemente saber si hay un usuario logueado y para eso existe la propiedad [currentUser](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#currentuser) que contiene un objeto `User` o `null` si no hay ninguna sesión iniciada. Entonces todo lo que necesitas hacer es un null check

```
comprobarAutentificacion()
  {
    return this.angularFireAuth.auth.currentUser != null;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
**Tienes varias maneras:**

    comprobarAutentificacion(){
    this.angularFireAuth.onAuthStateChanged(user=>{
      if(user){
        return true;   
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    });
  }
```

**otra manera sería retornar directamente lo que te envía firebase y luego validar fuera:**

```
comprobarAutentificacion()
  {
    return this.angularFireAuth.onAuthStateChanged();
  }
```

Comment: Pero qué es lo que me devuelve "return this.angularFireAuth.onAuthStateChanged():" una promesa? un boolean....

Comment: Aparte de eso, creo que no puedo devolver un "return" de la función principal comprobarAutentificacion()

Comment: El primer caso no es correcto, ya que la funcion `comprobarAutentificacion()` no devuelve nada